# A minimizing geodesic that intersect simple closed curve orthogonally

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

> Let $C$ be the trace of a simple closed curve in a regular surface $S$. Let $p\in S-C$. Assume that $p$ is close enough to $C$ that a normal ball about $p$ intersects $C$. Let $q\in C$ be the point of $C$ closest to $p$. Then a minimizing geodesic from $p$ to $q$ must intersect $C$ orthogonally.

The statement is intuitively clear but I don't know how to prove it. Should I parameterize $C$? How can I show the orthogonality?

Comment: have you seen the 'first variation of energy'-formula for a smooth curve?

Comment: @deb Unfortunately no. Other way to slove this without that?

Comment: you have seen normal neighbourhoods, have you seen Gauss's lemma?

Comment: @deb Yes, I've seen both of them

Comment: Gauss's lemma says that radial geodesics meet the boundary of the normal sphere perpendicularly.

Comment: @deb Ok, I see. So?